# Vertically Centering Values in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I've tried several variations based on search results and StackOverflow results and referenced existing code.

With this code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="table-row row d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
  <div class="col">
    <span class="align-middle">
      <button type="submit" class="searchbtn emailRemoveBtn float-start align-self-center" name="command" value="Delete email @i">
         <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark sm"></i>
         <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
    
      <input readonly class="align-self-center" style="border-style: hidden;" />
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The emails don't vertically center as shown here:

[image]

I'm new to this and it's probably something small.  Do you see what I'm missing to center the emails vertically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/) and [floats](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/float/) together.
2. Don't use floats at all, except to wrap text around images. They're not for structural layout, just for *content* layout.
3. Don't introduce table row layout here (unless you actually have tabular data).
4. Don't use rows *and* explicit flex layout. Bootstrap 5 rows *already* have flexbox applied, but they require containers and columns, which you apparently don't need here, having only one column per row. You could apply the same principles to [grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/) rows, though.
5. [`justify-content`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#justify-content) aligns content along the primary flex axis, not `align-items`.
6. Bootstrap provides [border classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/borders/#subtractive) which you can use to remove border. Custom styles should be put on custom classes anyway, not in the markup.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center mt-1 py-2  bg-secondary">
  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary searchbtn emailRemoveBtn" name="command" value="Delete email @i">
       <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark sm"></i>
       <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>

    <input readonly class="align-self-center border-0" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center mt-1 py-2 bg-secondary">
  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary searchbtn emailRemoveBtn" name="command" value="Delete email @i">
       <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark sm"></i>
       <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>

    <input readonly class="align-self-center border-0" />
  </div>
</div>
```